# How do I create a Smart Group of Participants using a Custom Data Field in Events?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, search, smartgroups, custom-search

We use the Events module to offer three main types of classes: adult art classes, youth art classes, and professional development workshops. Students register online. What I would like to be able to do is create Smart Groups of Participants based on the subject matter of the class, for example: painting, drawing, or portfolio review, so that we can mail to these groups and let them know about future classes they might be interested in. I created a Custom Data Field called "Class Department" with multiple choice options for the different subjects assigned to the Event types that we use for classes: Class (adult), Class (youth), and Workshop. My issue is that, having done that, I'm unable to use the "Class Department" data field as a search option in Advanced Search, even though I clicked the "is the event searchable?" box. Is this a version issue? We're still on 4.3.11. If this becomes available in later versions, what version does it first become available in?

Comment: Please upgrade to keep your site secure and safe. 4.6 is the current Long Term Stable Release, and 4.7 will become the next one. 4.5 and below no longer receive security support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked in 4.4 and 4.6.

It does not work in 4.4, but it does in 4.6.

So, not sure about 4.5, but if you upgrade that far I advise to upgrade to 4.6 anyway, because then you are on the current LTS (Long Term Support) version.